# Python How to remove \" from a string

Tags: python

I got this code from somewhere online, and saved it in a variable called "doc".

```
doc = """{"Grade": "  \"B+\"  "}"""
```

I want doc to print

```
{"Grade": "  B+  "}
```

So that I can use ast.literal_eval() to convert "doc" into a dictionary.

But when I try:

```
print(doc)
```

It prints:

```
{"Grade": "  "B+"  "}
```

Which is not what I want because then ast.literal_eval() won't work.

Or:

```
print(doc.replace("\"", ''))
```

which gives me:

```
{Grade:   B+  }
```

It completely removes the double quote, which is not what I want either because ast.literal_eval() gives an error.

So how can I change "doc" so that

```
doc = """{"Grade": "  \"B+\"  "}"""
```

can print the following code after some work?

```
{"Grade": "  B+  "}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't remember the exact syntax right now. But using the strip function might be the way to go

Comment: Inside the `"""` string there is no difference between `"` and `\"`. Both are just double quotes `"`. So you will have to use a regular expression that identifies the quotes in quotes.

Comment: I think there is an error in the original code. It should be: `doc = """{"Grade": "  \\"B+\\"  "}"""`, or `doc = r"""{"Grade": "  \"B+\"  "}"""`, which both directly give this string `'{"Grade": "  \\"B+\\"  "}'` which is parsable by litteral_eval. Trying to fix a string once it contains incorrect quoting cannot be done confidently, unless you have more knowledge (that you should share in question).

Comment: Hmmm, dumb question, but isn't that format basically "-escaped JSON?  If so, could you leverage json parsers to do part of the work?  Or could you rely on json parsers instead of AST?  i.e. are you trying to write your own json parser and why would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

We can just convert the repeated double quotes to a single set of double quotes with [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
In [95]: doc = """{"Grade": "  \"B+\"  "}"""

In [96]: doc
Out[96]: '{"Grade": "  "B+"  "}'

In [98]: re.sub(r'["]\s*["]', '"', doc)
Out[98]: '{"Grade": "B+"}'

In [99]: import ast

In [101]: doc = re.sub(r'["]\s*["]', '"', doc)

In [102]: ast.literal_eval(doc)
Out[102]: {'Grade': 'B+'}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I find out it works only if there is no other words around \"B+\". If doc = """{"Grade": " something \"B+\" something "}""", then I could not find it working.

Comment: Can you show an example input where it wouldn't work?

Comment: doc = """{"Grade": " something \"B+\" something "}"""

Comment: Can you do `doc = r"""{"Grade": " something \"B+\" something "}"""` instead?

Comment: No, it does not work. And I cannot manually do that because doc comes from somewhere else.

Comment: It comes from <pre> in .html. And there are lot of htmls with this structure.

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)        and then           
doc = soup.pre.string

Answer (score 1):

Ok I assume that you have a string in the form `{"key": "value"}` in which the value could contain unquoted double quotes. In your example, we have `Grade` for key and `"B+"` for value.

In that case, you can either remove the inner quotes or correctly quote them, but you should split the string to identify the *value* part

```
start, value, last = re.match(r'(\s*{\s*".*?"\s*:\s*")(.*)("\s*})', doc).groups()
```

You can then easily process quotes in the value part:

```
fixed = value.replace('"', "") # remove quotes
```

or

```
fixed = value.replace('"', r'\"') # correctly quotes the double quotes
```

You can then successfully write:

```
d = ast.litteral_eval(start + fixed + last)
```

and get either `{'Grade': '  B+  '}` or `{'Grade': '  "B+"  '}`